# Meaning of 'inherited institutions'

Tags: word-meaning

> Wars and economic dislocations always have been regarded as
> generation-defining events. Not surprisingly, Americans that came of
> age during a national emergency typically developed powerful
> collective identities, often oriented around an ethos of social
> discipline, secular progress, and confident public leadership. Three
> memorable examples are what Thomas Jefferson called his "generation of
> 1776" (the Revolutionary War); what Oliver Wendell Holmes, Jr., called
> his "generation touched with fire" (the Civil War); and what some
> historians call John F. Kennedy's "GI generation" (the Great
> Depression and World War II). Each of these generations entered public
> life at a conspicuously early age. With **inherited institutions** in
> disarray, their quick rise to power triggered epic struggles—which
> invariably unleashed generational tensions—over just how the political
> and economic deck would be reshuffled.

What is the meaning of 'inherited institutions' in the above context?

Comment: They're things like the legal system, royalty in the UK, the church, schools (the education system in general), national sports, etc. Stuff that was "handed down" from previous generations (and to which the current generation may make minor modifications, but more or less those institutions tend to continue relatively unchanged across generations).

Comment: (In your context, I suspect "The League of Nations", for example, was one of those "moribund" institutions that were in disarray. Or would be, if the context was a bit later.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I assumed that by inherited they only mean those institutions that are passed down to members of the family exclusively. So not gained through election. Could that be the meaning?

Comment: And the fact they are in 'disarray' at the point in history where people started gaining the right to elect their own officials.

Comment: I suppose I'd have to say that "inherited" here is a ***metaphoric*** usage. It's got no direct connection to families inheriting wealth and property from the previous generation when they die. Nor is the concept of democracy and elected officials relevant here. It''s just referring to ***all*** kinds of "social institutions" (governing pretty much all "organised" social interactions extending beyond a person's family and friends) that might have any kind of continuity from one generation to the next. By default, such institutions tend to become "hidebound" and hence inappropriate / imperfect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so inherited in the sense that the organizational structures and purposes of such institutions stay the same throughout generations?

Comment: The reason for the writer using this metaphoric reference in the first place is simply to convey the idea that *such institutions **often continue to exist** throughout generations*, regardless of whether or not they actually ***stay the same***. BUT - in the specific contexts he's interested in, some of those institutions may be "in disarray", and thus unable to effectively counter or moderate ***new*** changes in social organisation and ideas very effectively (so new things can become established much quicker than they would if the old things were still "fully functional" and appropriate).